# hashing a string using HMACSHA256 in C#

Tags: cryptography, hmac, sha256

```
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\xx.mac");
        byte[] hash;
        byte [] messageBytes;
        HMACSHA256 hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(bytes);
        messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);//this is the string which will be hashed
        hash = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        string s = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

How to use the shared binary key to hash the string. I have shared **binary** key stored in a file so I want to read the content of a file and use it to hash a string.
I want this accomplished in C#. How do I proceed?

**EDIT**: The hash that is generated does not match with the hash that is generated by the payment processor. We both are using the same string to hash

Comment: Did you already try reading the key from the file? I can't see any relevant code in the question.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the relevant code. The hash generated for the string does not match with the hash generated by the payment processor. We both are using the same string to generate the hash

Comment: Perhaps the message contains characters that cannot be represented in ASCII? I can't think of anything else.